# gulp-stylus does not compile files, process out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, stylus

I'm trying to run the `gulp-stylus` plugin to compile my stylus files, but when I run `gulp stylus` gulp says "starting task stylus," my CPU goes up to 100% and a little while later I get the following error:
`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory`

I've tried not returning the stream, but gulp then outputs that the task has started and completed but no files are created.

Do you know of a solution to this?  I really like gulp but if worst comes to worst I can switch to grunt.  Thanks for the help!

Relevant code:

```
gulp.task('stylus', function() {
  var stream = gulp.src('./src/css/styles.styl')
    .pipe(stylus())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/styles.css'));
  return stream;
});
```

Comment: can you add content of your styles.styl file, and what about styles.css file, better to use gulp.dest('./build/css/').

Comment: I decided to use a different plugin, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Gulp vs Grunt thing. The task just isn't written correctly. Try

```
// include the required packages. 
var gulp = require('gulp');
var stylus = require('gulp-stylus');

gulp.task('stylus', function () {
  gulp.src('./src/css/styles.styl')
    .pipe(stylus())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/'));
});
```

You can also refer to the [gulp-stylus documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-stylus) too

Usually when you get that error it means that you have an endless loop.
Stay awesome!